# drupal menu_alter looking for include file in the wrong place

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-hooks

I currently have a simple menu_alter hook in a new module I'm building which allows simple access control for menus:

```
<?php 

function amh_menu_menu_alter(&$items)
{
    $items['admin/build/menu/access'] = array(
    'title' => 'Access',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('amh_menu_access_configure'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer menu'),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => 5,
    'file' => 'amh_menu.admin.inc',
  );
}
```

However, I get the following error when loading the page:

```
[Mon Feb 21 11:25:15 2011] [error] [client 10.2.2.106] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): 
Failed opening required '/amh_menu.admin.inc' 
(include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') 
in /var/www/shop.dev.amh/www/includes/menu.inc on line 346, 
referer: http://shop.dev.amh/admin/build/menu
```

Looking at other modules which have menu and menu_alter hooks, they all refer to local module.admin.inc in places, and they don't have this problem and don't appear to specify any extra path.

Indeed - the documentation for menu hooks says that the "file path" menu item parameter is

> The path to the directory containing
>   the file specified in "file". This
>   defaults to the path to the module
>   implementing the hook.

How do I make this work?

Comment: Have you tried setting the "file path" parameter? Which version of Drupal? Maybe this is related: http://drupal.org/node/259133

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can explicitly set the file path to drupal_get_path('module', 'yourmodule'). That is the default, but the default is set before hook_menu_alter() is called.

The question is, why do you define a *new* menu item in hook_menu_*alter*() instead of hook_menu(). The alter hook is supposed to change existing hooks of other modules, not add new ones.

Comment: There are reasons to define new menu items in hook_menu_alter(), but they would be intentional. That said, setting the 'file path' element is the correct answer if default behavior is bugged. I've run into this problem before.

Comment: I'm using hook_menu_alter because I want to add a local task to an existing menu structure instead of completely replacing the menu that has already been built.

Comment: specifying the file path as you suggested turns the trick - thanks

Comment: There should be nothing stopping you from adding local tasks to a menu defined by another module in hook_menu(), have you tried it? The structure returned by hook_menu is flat, the menu system will then move it into the correct position on it's own. There might be other keys that you are missing that result in notices or similar